# Google Translate CLI

Tags: go, google-translate

A Translator in the Terminal using Golang. It uses Google's API. Currently, it only translates en (English) to es (Spanish).

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func (item *Result) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var v []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    item.Data = v[0].(interface{}).([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(string)
    return nil
}

type Result struct {
    Data interface{}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("\nEnter text\t: ")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    query := scanner.Text()
    response, err := http.Get("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q=" + url.QueryEscape(query))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        var result Result
        if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        value := result.Data
        fmt.Printf("Translation\t: %s\n", value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In several places you use `fmt.Println` followed by `os.Exit`.
You may create your own `Exit` function to write error message to `stderr` and terminate.

Note: it is common practice to write error messages to `stderr`.
`stdout` is for program output - translated text in your case.

---

```
item.Data = v[0].(interface{}).([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(string)
```

This statement will trigger a panic someday. I bet you need some [recover](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover).

---

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result); err != nil {
```

Hm, you've shaded previous `err`. Do you need one more `error` variable?
When you use `:=` operator, it will declare all missing variables on the left that *doesnt present in current scope*. Example:

```
str := "What??"
if str != "" {
    str := ""
    fmt.Printf("str is '%s'\n", str)
}
if str != "" { panic(str) }
```

---

Other notes:

- I see you've used `bufio.Scanner` to get first line from input. You may consider reading *all* via `ioutil.ReadAll`. This way one may pipe some text to your program: `cat ./text.txt | go-translate`
- No need for `else` branch in `main` function
- `value` variable is used only once. You may pass `result.Data` directly to `fmt.Printf` call.

Example:

```
func Exit(err interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "\nEnter text\t: ")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    query := scanner.Text()

    response, err := http.Get("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q=" + url.QueryEscape(query))
    if err != nil {
       Exit(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        Exit(err)
    }

    var result Result
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result); err != nil {
         Exit(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Translation\t: %s\n", result.Data)
}
```